# Unable to reach docker container from outside

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I have a fairly straight forward Docker stack setup. I have one node in the cluster at this time (the manager node). On this cluster I am running one portainer agent (portainer_agent) to keep an eye on the node and the portainer web interface (portainer_portainer).

The issue I have run into is that when I am ssh'd into the node, I can access portainer_portainer on its published port (`localhost:9000`). However, when I attempt to access that same port (`10.0.0.6:9000`) on the node's external ip address from my desktop browser (not on the cluster node) I am unable to get any data from the container. Is there something I have done wrong? I have included my docker inspect for portainer_portainer.

docker version on linux

```
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
```

portainer_portainer inspect

```
ID:             j62wg3sgry5326h4gli3apvxe
Name:           portainer_portainer
Labels:
 com.docker.stack.image=portainer/portainer
 com.docker.stack.namespace=portainer
Service Mode:   Replicated
 Replicas:      1
UpdateStatus:
 State:         completed
 Started:       57 seconds ago
 Completed:     44 seconds ago
 Message:       update completed
Placement:
 Constraints:   [node.role == manager]
UpdateConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Update order:      stop-first
RollbackConfig:
 Parallelism:   1
 On failure:    pause
 Monitoring Period: 5s
 Max failure ratio: 0
 Rollback order:    stop-first
ContainerSpec:
 Image:         portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:f8c2b0a9ca640edf508a8a0830cf1963a1e0d2fd9936a64104b3f658e120b868
 Args:          -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 
Mounts:
 Target:        /data
  Source:       /mnt/portainer/data
  ReadOnly:     false
  Type:         bind
Resources:
Networks: portainer_agent_network 
Endpoint Mode:  vip
Ports:
 PublishedPort = 8000
  Protocol = tcp
  TargetPort = 8000
  PublishMode = ingress
 PublishedPort = 9000
  Protocol = tcp
  TargetPort = 8000
  PublishMode = ingress
```

Edit: Upon further inspection. the containers are, in fact reachable. However, they are only reachable when connected to the VPN service on my firewall. This tells me that the service are being published properly, but they remain unavailable from my local network (this is going to be key to my continuing on with docker).

Comment: `However, when I attempt to access that same port (9000) from my desktop browser ` What IP address and port are you typing in to your browser?

Comment: I am using the external port of my node. I have update my question with that information

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose.yml file?  Wondering how your port mapping looks like for the service

Comment: Also - do you know if there is some sort of firewall that could prevent that connection from being made? Is the 10.0.0.6 address accessible from outside your cluster node?

Comment: @Byob I have included my docker service inspect, which provides more information than my docker-compose file. `10.0.0.6` is the address of the node on my network that I use to access it via ssh.

Comment: I wonder if swarm is assigning the service a vip that you will need to use, based on the ‘ Endpoint Mode:  vip’ attribute, instead of the node ip.

Comment: @byob i had a look at the container that holds portainer. it has an ip address of `10.0.0.38`. when I attempt to connect to the ip on port 9000, I get "unable to connect" which tells me that the port is not actually open. or that the ip is not actually on my network.

Comment: Upon further inspection. the containers are, in fact reachable. However, they are only reachable when connected to the VPN service on my firewall. This tells me that the service are being published properly, but they remain unavailable from my local network (this is going to be key to my continuing on with docker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after some digging around, it would appear that I did not specify my question well enough. My home network is on the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet, as it the default docker ingress network. I rebuilt my docker swarm, and that being done, following the official docker tutorial on replacing the default ingress network. The commands I used were the following:

```
docker network rm ingress
```

```
docker network create --driver overlay --ingress --subnet=10.0.1.0/24 --gateway=10.0.1.2 ingress
```

Once all of that was done, I reinitialized my docker services. Everything came up and was available on my network.